# How can I smooth out the curves of a drawn Path using SwiftUI with a fat Stroke?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am making a basic drawing app and using the following tutorial to allow the user to draw:

https://martinmitrevski.com/2019/07/20/developing-drawing-app-with-swiftui/

The drawings are made using a DragGesture and then seaming together all the points observed in the onChange

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    Path { path in
        for drawing in self.drawings {
            self.add(drawing: drawing, toPath: &path)
        }
        self.add(drawing: self.currentDrawing, toPath: &path)
    }
    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 15.0)
    .background(Color(white: 0.95))
    .gesture(
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.1)
            .onChanged({ (value) in
                let currentPoint = value.location
                if currentPoint.y >= 0
                    && currentPoint.y < geometry.size.height {
                    self.currentDrawing.points.append(currentPoint)
                }
                
            })
            .onEnded({ (value) in
                self.drawings.append(self.currentDrawing)
                self.currentDrawing = Drawing()
            })
    )
}
.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)



private func add(drawing: Drawing, toPath path: inout Path) {
        let points = drawing.points
        if points.count > 1 {
            for i in 0..<points.count-1 {
                let current = points[i]
                let next = points[i+1]
                path.move(to: current)
                path.addLine(to: next)
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue I'm having is that for fatter strokes the curves are badly broken up as shown below.

[image]

Is there anyway to smoothen out these curves using this approach?

Comment: You should probably only be calling `path.move(to: current)` on the ***first*** point, then `path.addLine(to: next)` for the rest of the points.

Comment: Since that helps, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently creating a new line segment for **every** point.

What you likely want to do is `move To:` the **first** point, and then `addLine: To` the successive points:

```
private func add(drawing: Drawing, toPath path: inout Path) {
    let points = drawing.points
    if points.count > 1 {
        path.move(to: points[0])
        for i in 1..<points.count-1 {
            path.addLine(to: points[i])
        }
    }
}
```